# Comparing duplicates between two data sets and using a mathematical function in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am currently struggling with the following problem:

As you can see in the picture, I have two datasets.

I'd like to scan and compare column `A` and `D`, and look for duplicates. If there are duplicates, I'd like to find the quotient of the values of the respective `B` and `E` cells.

For example, the value `69` occurs in `A` and in `D`, and hence I'd like to have the quotient `1.2` and `4.4` in a new cell.

[image]

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add desured output, please.

Comment: Could there be more than one match? i.e. could `69` appear twice in either column `A` or column `D`? (side note: I edited your question so it refers to Excel`s column labels to avoid confusion)

Comment: I believe it will be easier with VBA.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but how it is done will be different depending how you answer the above comments. Please edit your question and also let us know what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Dear Lana, what is the output value if I choose 87 ?

Answer (score 1):

The following formula gets any matches and displays the results in a single cell:

```
=INDEX($B$3:$B$11,MATCH(D3,$A$3:$A$11,0))&  " : "&E3
```

MATCH looks for a specific value (55 in D3) in the array A3:A11.  The INDEX function retrieves the corresponding row in the array B3:B11.

You can add an if clause to ensure the match is found (and if not, don't display anything):

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(D3,$A$3:$A$11,0)),"",INDEX($B$3:$B$11,MATCH(D3,$A$3:$A$11,0))&  " : "&E3)
```

[image: Excel Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

*Combination of `INDEX & MATCH` wrapped with `VLOOKUP` solves the issue:*

[image]

- Formula in Cell `U3`:

  `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDEX(O$3:O$11,MATCH(R3,R$3:R$11,0)),O$3:P$11,2,FALSE)&" : "&VLOOKUP(INDEX(O$3:O$11,MATCH(R3,R$3:R$11,0)),R$3:S$11,2,FALSE),"")`

**N.B.**

- *Formula starts with `69`, `68`, `3`, `7` and at last `55`, reads values from `O3:O11`.*
- *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*